# Applying condition based on primary key match in sql tables

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I have two tables, tbl1 and tbl2 in Synapse. I need to insert entries from tbl2 into tbl1. The condition is if there's a primary key match(key can be id or name), then update the record. If there's no primary key match, then insert the new record. How can I do this using t-sql's exist condition. Do I need to use if..then..else and if so how?

```
SELECT a.PID, a.FName
FROM dbo.tbl1 as a
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * 
  FROM dbo.tbl2 as b
  WHERE a.FName = b.FName)
```

Comment: What you need to do is an "Upsert"; an `UPDATE` followed by an `INSERT`.

Comment: is there an example I can see?

Comment: A search of the term will give you 1,000's.

Comment: Hi @py_noob, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 1):

As said by @larnu in the above comment, you need to **insert followed by update or vice-versa to Insert Record if not exist** and `update if exist from one table to another table`.

***Sample code: -***

***--Insert the different primary key--***

```
  INSERT  INTO Table1 (Id, Name)
  SELECT a.Id,a.Name FROM Table2 AS a
  WHERE  NOT  EXISTS
   (SELECT * FROM Table1 as b WHERE a.Name = b.Name)
```

***--Update the value of primary key if exist as below--***

```
    Update a
    set a.Id = b.Id
    ,a.Name = b.Name
    from Table1 as a
    join Table2 as b
    on a.Name = b.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late, I'm surprised no one mentioned it, but in T-SQL, there is a MERGE statement, that might fit your needs. It would go like this:

```
MERGE dbo.tbl1 AS [target]
USING (SELECT id, FName, column1, column2) AS [source]
ON [target].FName = [source].FNAME
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET [target].column1 = [source].column1,
    [target].column2 = [source].column2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (fname, column1, column2) VALUES ([source].fname, [source].column1, [source].column2)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    DELETE;
```